# Test vectors for SIT -encryption algorithm?

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design

Test vectors for SIT -encryption algorithm?

I'm looking for Tests Vectors to test my implementation of SIT.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does SIT stand for? What defines what "SIT -encryption algorithm" is? That's not a well-known cryptographic algorithm to me. The closest it rings in my mind is the file extension and nick for StuffIt, a commercial file compression tool with encryption option.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.08688.pdf This is what SIT is. Actually, I am looking forward to design hardware for lightweight block cipher which is popular and well known. If you know of a popular lightweight block cipher, please let me know. Thank you. [moderator note: when adding to a comment within the 5mn allowance, please edit it]

Comment: My advice to a student assigned to work specifically on that paper would be to question the motivations of the assignment. The paper's section 4 E. SQUARE Attack is enough to cast doubt on the whole thing; "This attack was presented by [P.  Barreto and  V. Rijmen] to realize how efficiently the algorithm performs against it. The attack is able to recover one byte of the last key and the rest of keys can be recovered by repeating the attack eight times. However to be able to do so, the attack requires $2^8$ key guesses by $2^8$ plaintexts which is equal to $2^{16}$ S-box lookups."

Comment: In addition to the square attack, there's also a fairly obvious partial differential with probability circa $2^{-24}$; along with a block size and key size of 64 bits, it's not clear why anyone is bothering with this...

Comment: Well, the authors probably had to write it to get their degree or something similar. It seems to be a IJACSA  released paper that nobody took a serious look at - unfortunately.

Comment: For the record, I found a probability 1 partial differential through the entire cipher; if the delta of inputs bits 32-47 is $\delta$ (and other bits are the same), then the delta of output bits 16-31 xored with $F(bits 0-15)$ of the output will also be $\delta$.  Perhaps the best thing about this cipher would be that it would appear to be good practice for a budding cryptanalyst who knows the basics...